# Threads not stop in python

Tags: python, multithreading, download

The purpose of my program is to download files with threads. I define the unit, and using len/unit threads, the len is the length of the file which is going to be downloaded.

Using my program, the file can be downloaded, but the threads are not stopping. I can't find the reason why.

This is my code...

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import urllib2
import threading
import os
from time import ctime

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
 def __init__(self,func,args,name=''):
  threading.Thread.__init__(self);
  self.func = func;
  self.args = args;
  self.name = name;
 def run(self):
  apply(self.func,self.args);

url = 'http://ubuntuone.com/1SHQeCAQWgIjUP2945hkZF';
request = urllib2.Request(url);
response = urllib2.urlopen(request);
meta = response.info();
response.close();
unit = 1000000;
flen = int(meta.getheaders('Content-Length')[0]);
print flen;
if flen%unit == 0:
 bs = flen/unit;
else :
 bs = flen/unit+1;
blocks = range(bs);
cnt = {};
for i in blocks:
 cnt[i]=i;
def getStr(i):
 try:
  print 'Thread %d start.'%(i,);
  fout = open('a.zip','wb');
  fout.seek(i*unit,0);
  if (i+1)*unit > flen:
   request.add_header('Range','bytes=%d-%d'%(i*unit,flen-1));
  else :
   request.add_header('Range','bytes=%d-%d'%(i*unit,(i+1)*unit-1));
  #opener = urllib2.build_opener();
  #buf = opener.open(request).read();
  resp = urllib2.urlopen(request);
  buf = resp.read();
  fout.write(buf);
 except BaseException:
  print 'Error';
 finally :
  #opener.close();
  fout.flush();
  fout.close();
  del cnt[i];
# filelen = os.path.getsize('a.zip');
 print 'Thread %d ended.'%(i),
 print cnt;
# print 'progress : %4.2f'%(filelen*100.0/flen,),'%';
def main():
 print 'download at:',ctime();
 threads = [];
 for i in blocks:
  t = MyThread(getStr,(blocks[i],),getStr.__name__);
  threads.append(t);
 for i in blocks:
  threads[i].start();
 for i in blocks:
#  print 'this is the %d thread;'%(i,);
  threads[i].join();
 #print 'size:',os.path.getsize('a.zip');
 print 'download done at:',ctime();
if __name__=='__main__':
 main();
```

Could someone please help me understand why the threads aren't stopping.

Comment: You don't need `;` in Python :)

Comment: Well, couple things.  Your formatting is bad - code like this tends to just get skipped over and the skilled and experienced developers on here just go on to another question where their time and skill will not be wasted on deciphering the text.  Next - what debugging have you done yourself?  What happens with just one download thread? Where does the thread get stuck?  What is the last line executed before it blocks?  Any error messages, exception messageBoxes etc?  Surely you haven't just noted that your code does not work and just dumped the lot on us, (again)?

Comment: Are you coming from another language and writing python from that perspective? Also, why do you subclass Thread only to do the exact same thing it already does?

Comment: The program didn't stop,and there is no error,no any message,everytimes the thread which didn't stop is different.Using one thread is ok.Sorry for my worse formatting.Thanks

Comment: I just ran your program. All your threads complete and the program ends. The only reason I can see off-hand that it doesn't work is if any of your threads have a stall in the network request.

Comment: some threads have a stall in the network request,and I don't know the reason,can you teach me,thanks

Comment: I don't know whats happening with your networking connection. You are doing a url open and read without any timeouts, so the request can just run forever. It would probably need to be a thing where you have a reasonable timeout, and if it fails then you put the request back into a queue. I would also not spawn 40 threads to do this. I would create a thread pool, and a queue of work, and have threads looping over the queue

Comment: Thank you jdi, I'm going to modify the program

Comment: Off topic: I highly recommend you read (and follow) [_PEP8 -- Style Guide for Python Code_](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) because you managed to make your code very unreadable which is one of Python's great strengths.

Comment: Other person use 4 spaces,and I use 1 space,just different custom.Of course,I'll change to 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really address your code example because it is quite messy and hard to follow, but a potential reason you are seeing the threads not end is that a request will stall out and never finish. `urllib2` allows you to specify timeouts for how long you will allow the request to take.

What I would recommend for your own code is that you split your work up into a queue, start a fixed number of thread (instead of a variable number), and let the worker threads pick up work until it is done. Make the http requests have a timeout. If the timeout expires, try again or put the work back into the queue.

Here is a generic example of how to use a queue, a fixed number of workers and a sync primitive between them:

```
import threading
import time
from Queue import Queue

def worker(queue, results, lock):
    local_results = []
    while True:
        val = queue.get()
        if val is None:
            break

        # pretend to do work
        time.sleep(.1)
        local_results.append(val)

    with lock:
        results.extend(local_results)
        print threading.current_thread().name, "Done!"


num_workers = 4

threads = []
queue = Queue()
lock = threading.Lock()
results = []

for i in xrange(100):
    queue.put(i)

for _ in xrange(num_workers):

    # Use None as a sentinel to signal the threads to end
    queue.put(None)

    t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(queue,results,lock))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for t in threads:
    t.join()

print sorted(results)

print "All done"
```

Comment: thank you jdi,I'll try it as you said with queue and a fixed threads and setting the timeout in request.

Comment: I have a feeling this will help since you will be more finely controlling the number of http requests you are spawning. I know my example doesn't show it but make sure to do your requests with a timeout so you don't even allow them to hang